# Firestore Get all Documents and Display as HTML Table on Google App Script Web App

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-cloud-firestore

Thank you in advance.

Need help on using  [FirestoreGoogleAppsScript](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript) library. Need to pull all documents and display on an HTML Table. I was able to use allDocumentsRows = firestore.getDocuments("StudentInfo"); but I'm getting several data not sure how to parse please see result below.

Again thank you so much

Below is my Firestore:

```
[{"name":"projects/aerobic-rampart-310908/databases/(default)/documents/StudentInfo/2kVWabLEOIklMjFjSx8Z","fields":{"Lname":{"stringValue":"Neman"},"Gender":{"stringValue":"Male"},"StudID":{"stringValue":"P1003"},"Fname":{"stringValue":"Mike"},"Age":{"stringValue":"30"}},"createTime":"2021-04-19T01:19:07.244542Z","updateTime":"2021-04-19T01:20:07.525386Z","readTime":"2021-04-19T04:49:08.022505Z"},{"name":"projects/aerobic-rampart-310908/databases/(default)/documents/StudentInfo/5alVKxcuefigpDJxVz42","fields":{"StudID":{"stringValue":"P1003"},"Lname":{"stringValue":"Neman"},"Gender":{"stringValue":"Male"},"Age":{"stringValue":"30"},"Fname":{"stringValue":"Mike"}},"createTime":"2021-04-19T01:20:17.336285Z","updateTime":"2021-04-19T01:20:17.336285Z","readTime":"2021-04-19T04:49:08.022505Z"},{"name":"projects/aerobic-rampart-310908/databases/(default)/documents/StudentInfo/PUfVFCSSvb6Ocsg8GuL9","fields":{"StudID":{"stringValue":"P1003"},"Fname":{"stringValue":"Mike"},"Lname":{"stringValue":"Neman"},"Gender":{"stringValue":"Male"},"Age":{"stringValue":"30"}},"createTime":"2021-04-19T01:20:14.947172Z","updateTime":"2021-04-19T01:20:14.947172Z","readTime":"2021-04-19T04:49:08.022505Z"},{"name":"projects/aerobic-rampart-310908/databases/(default)/documents/StudentInfo/SKskdYQO6YQv0jPN16ma","fields":{"Age":{"stringValue":"30"},"Lname":{"stringValue":"Neman"},"Fname":{"stringValue":"Mike"},"Gender":{"stringValue":"Male"},"StudID":{"stringValue":"P1003"}},"createTime":"2021-04-19T01:20:19.429915Z","updateTime":"2021-04-19T01:20:19.429915Z","readTime":"2021-04-19T04:49:08.022505Z"},{"name":"projects/aerobic-rampart-310908/databases/(default)/documents/StudentInfo/bWmpnwK5iuUuhJ5jEG6c","fields":{"Gender":{"stringValue":"Male"},"StudID":{"stringValue":"P1003"},"Lname":{"stringValue":"Neman"},"Age":{"stringValue":"30"},"Fname":{"stringValue":"Mike"}},"createTime":"2021-04-19T01:20:18.516428Z","updateTime":"2021-04-19T01:20:18.516428Z","readTime":"2021-04-19T04:49:08.022505Z"},{"name":"projects/aerobic-rampart-310908/databases/(default)/documents/StudentInfo/gpIqfyWpHJBNosJuOJSw","fields":{"Age":{"stringValue":"30"},"Fname":{"stringValue":"Mike"},"Lname":{"stringValue":"Neman"},"StudID":{"stringValue":"P1003"},"Gender":{"stringValue":"Male"}},"createTime":"2021-04-19T01:20:22.676022Z","updateTime":"2021-04-19T01:20:22.676022Z","readTime":"2021-04-19T04:49:08.022505Z"}]
```

Comment: If you could post the contents of the second image into your question it would be a lot easier to read and determine the  structure.  I believe you could [format it as code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Hi, @Cooper, thanks for the reply already put the contents.

Comment: can you post it as valid JSON

Comment: Not sure because its the actual return value of the FirestoreGASLibray  (firestore.getDocuments). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from Firestore and you want to create a HTML table using the retrieved values using Google Apps Script.

When the sample value of `allDocumentsRows = firestore.getDocuments("StudentInfo")` is the values in your question, and the header row is `["Age", "Fname", "Lname", "StudID", "Gender"]`, the sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
const allDocumentsRows = firestore.getDocuments("StudentInfo"); // This script is from your question.

const headers = ["Age", "Fname", "Lname", "StudID", "Gender"]; // As the header row, please set the keys in fields with the order you want to use.
const h = headers.reduce((s, e) => s += `<th>${e}</th>`, "<tr>") + "</tr>";
const htmlTable = allDocumentsRows.reduce((s, {fields}) =>
  s += headers.reduce((t, hed) => t += `<td>${fields[hed].stringValue}</td>`, "<tr>") + "</tr>"
, `<table>${h}`) + "</table>";
console.log(htmlTable)
```

#### Result:

When above script is used for your sample value, the following result is obtained.

```html
<table><tr><th>Age</th><th>Fname</th><th>Lname</th><th>StudID</th><th>Gender</th></tr><tr><td>30</td><td>Mike</td><td>Neman</td><td>P1003</td><td>Male</td></tr><tr><td>30</td><td>Mike</td><td>Neman</td><td>P1003</td><td>Male</td></tr><tr><td>30</td><td>Mike</td><td>Neman</td><td>P1003</td><td>Male</td></tr><tr><td>30</td><td>Mike</td><td>Neman</td><td>P1003</td><td>Male</td></tr><tr><td>30</td><td>Mike</td><td>Neman</td><td>P1003</td><td>Male</td></tr><tr><td>30</td><td>Mike</td><td>Neman</td><td>P1003</td><td>Male</td></tr></table>
```

#### Note:

- When you want to change the order of the header, please modify `const headers = ["Age", "Fname", "Lname", "StudID", "Gender"]`.

#### Reference:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for the help. You are a life save.

Comment: @Edward James Smith II Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Question, @Tanaike, 
How to do the above but without the FirestoreGoogleAppsScript library? Please have sample codes.

Also I follow you on Gith, you are the best, thanks.